# wkwebview run local html (in document) Received an unexpected URL from the web process

Tags: html, iframe, document, wkwebview

Two questions：

1.access files as .css .js should through fullPath as the code in index.html you see;

2.when index.html's codes run to "document.body.appendChild(iFrame)", simulator run to blank；and xcode log:

Received an unexpected URL from the web process:'file:///Users/John_Chen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20ABEC24-78BD-4577-9AA5-35CB1520F620/data/Containers/Data/Application/30A53A36-4A05-4491-A400-CEBF5F9E7D21/Documents/test/2.html'
Received an invalid message "WebPageProxy.DecidePolicyForNavigationAction" from the web process.

Anybody can help? TKS!

iOS code:

1.unZip test.zip to document:

```
- (void)copyFloderToSandbox
{
   NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSString *originalPlayerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"zip"];
   NSString *originalMovi_01Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movi_01" ofType:@"zip"];
   NSString *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
   NSString *PDoc = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];
   NSString *MDoc = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movi_01"];

  if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:PDoc]) 
 {
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:originalPlayerPath toDestination:documentPath];
 }
  if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:MDoc]) 
 {
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:originalMovi_01Path toDestination:documentPath];
 }
}
```

2.WKWebView load index.html:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self copyFloderToSandbox];

self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds configuration:[self configWeb]];
_webView.navigationDelegate = self;
_webView.UIDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_webView];


NSString *playerPath = [OMDBManager getLocalDataFilePathWithPathComponent:@"test"];
NSString *html = [playerPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
NSString *moviePath = [OMDBManager getLocalDataFilePathWithPathComponent:@"movi_01"];
NSString *moviParameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"movieroot=%@",playerPath];
NSString *playParameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"playerroot=%@",playerPath];
NSString *baseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@&%@",html,moviParameter,playParameter];

NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:baseString isDirectory:YES];
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:html encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:baseUrl];
}

- (WKWebViewConfiguration *)configWeb
{
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration      alloc]init];
configuration.preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc]init];
configuration.preferences.minimumFontSize = 18;
configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;
configuration.userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc]init];
[configuration.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"readJsonFile"];
return configuration;
 }
```

[image: files in document directory]
[image: codes in index.html]

Comment: exactly  i am facing same issue now, do you have swift version? if yes can you update it. Also i have raised question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187859/how-to-load-file-directory-to-local-html-file-in-ios-swift

Answer (score 4):

I think it is because you aren't using the method `loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:`
The second argument would be the directory the html lies in.

Comment: I had solved it on the gitHub for reason that WKWebview's bug.So i replace it by UIWebView.

Comment: I think you should give it another try, because UIWebView is so much slower than WKWebView

Comment: Ben W is right. It's not a bug. You need to allow read access to the directory containing your file and assets using loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL

Comment: @JonphyChen exactly  i am facing same issue now, do you have swift version? if yes can you update it. Also i have raised question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187859/how-to-load-file-directory-to-local-html-file-in-ios-swift

Comment: @ParameswaranV I can't see that question, but I just had this problem in Swift and Ben W's answer worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, with Apple blocking apps that use UIWebView from the App Store later this year, going back to that is no longer an option at all.